# Recorrer ficheros con lo que almaceno en diccionario

Tags: python

Buenas estoy haciendo un pequño programa donde primero guardo en un array distintas lineas que quiero posteriormente leer de unos ficheros, tengo estos valores almacenados en mi dicionario:

```
{0: 96, 1: 192}
{0: 90, 1: 180, 2: 270, 3: 360, 4: 450}
{0: 93, 1: 186, 2: 279, 3: 372, 4: 465}
{0: 84, 1: 168, 2: 252, 3: 336, 4: 420, 5: 504}
{0: 93, 1: 186, 2: 279, 3: 372}
{0: 90, 1: 180}
{0: 90, 1: 180, 2: 270}
{0: 92}
```

Cada linea es un fichero y las lineas que quiero que me lea es decir primero del 0 al 96 y luego del 97 al 192 y luego lo mismo con los siguientes y las lineas alamacenadas.

No doy con la manera de poder hacerlo me quedo atascado aqui. Si necesitais que os ponga el codigo esta es la funcion con lo que ya obtengo los valores que quiero del diccionario.

```
    dictOfWords = {i: quepasa[i] for i in range(0, len(quepasa))}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
# abrimos y leemos el archivo
def open_file(filename):
    data = None
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        f.close()
    return data

#obtenemos la lineas
def getLines(file,inicio,final=None,salto=None):
    # si no se envia un final
    # se retorna solo esa linea
    if final == None:
        return file[inicio]
    if salto == None:
        # si se espefica un final
        return file[inicio:final]
    # si se especifica un salto
    return file[inicio:final:salto]

# leemos el archivo
file = open_file("sqlserver.txt")

# recuperamos las lineas
lineas= getLines(file,0,96)

print(lineas)
```

resumido:

```
data = None
filename = "file.txt"

with open(filename,"r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()

getLines = filename[0,96]
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo exactamente la salida que quieres, pero si necesitas generar un rango de valores dependiendo de los diccionarios, entonces puedes hacer algo así.

```
dct = {0: 93, 1: 186, 2: 279, 3: 372, 4: 465}

i = 0;
for key, value in dct.items():
    inicio = i
    final = value
    print(f"Procesando {inicio} a {final}") # Python 3.6+
    # [ aqui tu rutina de leer el fichero [inicio, final]
    i = value + 1
```

Da la salida:

```
Procesando 0 a 93
Procesando 94 a 186
Procesando 187 a 279
Procesando 280 a 372
Procesando 373 a 465
```

Si quieres procesar toda la lista (o *array*), con el siguiente formato:

```
array = [{0: 96, 1: 192}, 
{0: 90, 1: 180, 2: 270, 3: 360, 4: 450},
{0: 93, 1: 186, 2: 279, 3: 372, 4: 465}
# .... mas diccionarios
]
for dct in array:
    i = 0;
    for key, value in dct.items():
        inicio = i
        final = value
        print(f"Procesando {inicio} a {final}")
        # [ aqui tu rutina de leer el fichero [inicio, final]
        i = value + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No se la salida que esperas, pero ésto es realmente irrelevante para el algoritmo. Por ejemplo, para `{0: 96, 1: 192}` voy a asumir que quieres un diccionario también de salida con la estructura:

```
{
     0: ["linea 0", "linea 1", ..., "linea 96"],
     1: ["linea 95", "linea 96", ..., "linea 192"]
}
```

Si asumimos que tus diccionarios están ordenados y que usas Python >= 3.7 (si no no podemos asumir orden en los diccionarios), puedes aprovecharte simplemente de que el fichero implementa el protocolo iterador, puedes generar el diccionario con una sola lectura y sin necesidad de cargar el fichero al completo en memoria:

**`Python >= 3.7 y diccionario ordenado`**

```
def get_lines(dictionary, file_path, *args, **kwargs):
    out = {key: [] for key in dictionary}
    acum = 0
    with open(file_path, *args, **kwargs) as file:
        for key, break_point in dictionary.items():
            for line in file:
                out[key].append(line)
                acum += 1
                if acum > break_point:
                    break
        return out
```

**`Python >= 3.8 y diccionario ordenado`**

```
def get_lines(dictionary, file_path, *args, **kwargs):
    out = {key: [] for key in dictionary}
    acum = 0
    with open(file_path, *args, **kwargs) as file:
        for key, break_point in dictionary.items():
            for line in file:
                out[key].append(line)
                if (acum:= acum + 1) > break_point:
                    break
        return out
```

Ejemplo de llamada:

```
diccionario = {0: 84, 1: 168, 2: 252, 3: 336, 4: 420, 5: 504}
lineas = get_lines(didccionario, "test.txt")
```